# How to Hide/show list based on select option in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm beginner in web design HTML/CSS/JAvascript.

I have a form with a drop/down list  and  some unordered list (one for each option, all hide).
I would like to show the corresponding list based on the selected option in the drop/down list.

`<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" >
    <option value=''> </options>
    <option value="option1"> option1 </option>
    <option value="option2"> option2 </option>
    <option value="option3"> option3 </option>
</select>

<ul id='option1' style='display:none'>
   <li> list option1 </li>
   <li> list option1 </li>
</ul>

<ul id='option2' style='display:none'>
   <li> list option2</li>
   <li> list option2 </li>
</ul>

<ul id='option3' style='display:none'>
   <li> list option3</li>
   <li> list option3 </li>
</ul>`

It's a sample, i have more than 20 options and i can't code in if-else mode because number can evoluate.

Someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I work only with javascript (no Jquery)

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your best attempt and explain what went wrong (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Comment: Add an event listener to the dropdown listening for the `change` event, and use `this.value` as the id of the list to show.

Comment: Do you have multiple lists to enable show/hide or is there another reason for multiple lists

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var ddl = document.querySelector('#dropdown');
var prevEl;
function changeDDL(){
  if(prevEl){
     prevEl.style.display = "none";
   }
  var id = ddl.value;
  if(id){
    var el = document.querySelector('#'+id);
    el.style.display = "block";
    prevEl = el;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="changeDDL()">
    <option value=''> </options>
    <option value="option1"> option1 </option>
    <option value="option2"> option2 </option>
    <option value="option3"> option3 </option>
</select>

<ul id='option1' style='display:none'>
   <li> list option1 </li>
   <li> list option1 </li>
</ul>

<ul id='option2' style='display:none'>
   <li> list option2</li>
   <li> list option2 </li>
</ul>

<ul id='option3' style='display:none'>
   <li> list option3</li>
   <li> list option3 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a class to hide the elements. You can then use javascript to add and remove the class. The reason behind adding and removing a class with `display:none` is to cater for elements that have a display other than block.

```js
//Get the lists and store in a variable
let optionLists = document.querySelectorAll("ul[id^=option]");
//Set a contant for the class, if we change the class name we only have to change it once
const HIDDEN_CLASS = "hidden";

//Set an event handler on the dropdown
document.getElementById("dropdown").addEventListener("change", function(){
  //Selected Value
  var val = this.value;
  //Loop through the lists
  for(var i = 0; i < optionLists.length; i++) {
    //If the list has the matching ID
    if(optionLists[i].id === val){
      //Remove the hidden class
      optionLists[i].classList.remove(HIDDEN_CLASS);
    //Otherwise if the list does not have the hidden class
    }else if(!optionLists[i].classList.contains(HIDDEN_CLASS)){
      //Add the hidden class
      optionLists[i].classList.add(HIDDEN_CLASS);    
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" >
    <option value=''> </option>
    <option value="option1"> option1 </option>
    <option value="option2"> option2 </option>
    <option value="option3"> option3 </option>
</select>

<ul id='option1' class="hidden">
   <li> list option1 </li>
   <li> list option1 </li>
</ul>

<ul id='option2' class="hidden">
   <li> list option2</li>
   <li> list option2 </li>
</ul>

<ul id='option3' class="hidden">
   <li> list option3</li>
   <li> list option3 </li>
</ul>
```

You could also do this in a single list using data [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Note that the basics of this still works even though `li` are `display:list-item`.

```js
//Get the list items
let options = document.querySelectorAll("#options > li");
//Constant for the class
const HIDDEN_CLASS = "hidden";

//Add event listener to the dropdown
document.getElementById("dropdown").addEventListener("change", function(){
  //Selected value
  var val = this.value;
  //Loop throug the list items
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    //Id the list item has a matching data attribute
    if(options[i].dataset.option === val){
      //Remove the hidden class
      options[i].classList.remove(HIDDEN_CLASS);
    //Otherwise id the list item does not have the hidden class  
    }else if(!options[i].classList.contains(HIDDEN_CLASS)){
      //Add it
      options[i].classList.add(HIDDEN_CLASS);    
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" >
    <option value=''> </option>
    <option value="option1"> option1 </option>
    <option value="option2"> option2 </option>
    <option value="option3"> option3 </option>
</select>

<ul id="options">
   <li class="hidden" data-option="option1"> list option1 </li>
   <li class="hidden" data-option="option1"> list option1 </li>
   <li class="hidden" data-option="option2"> list option2</li>
   <li class="hidden" data-option="option2"> list option2 </li>
   <li class="hidden" data-option="option3"> list option3</li>
   <li class="hidden" data-option="option3"> list option3 </li>
   <li class="hidden" data-option="option2"> list option2 </li>
   <li class="hidden" data-option="option1"> list option1 </li>
   <li class="hidden" data-option="option3"> list option3</li>
</ul>
```